# Angularjs checklist-model - disable unchecked boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Hey superheroes of Stackoverflow. I am currently working on a checklist using angularjs and the checklist-model directive. I am trying to figure out how I can diable all the unchecked boxes when reaching x-amount of checked  boxes.

I am fetching data from a json file, hence the reason for my checkboxes being in a ng-repeat.

For now I am disabling all checkboxes. when reaching x-number of checked. Unfortunately the users should be able to change what has been chosen.

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:item_position"> 
<h3>{{item.item_name}}</h3>
<p>{{item.item_position}}</p>
<!--checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="item.answers.length >= 12" checklist-model="item.answers" checklist-value="player">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try in your ng-disabled:

`ng-disabled="item.answers.length >= 12 && item.answers === player"`

However it would be useful if you'd posted a jsfiddle with your directive and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this attribute on your checkbox input to perform the desired restriction:

```
ng-disabled="!checked && item.answers.length >= 12"
```